# using **to follow** or **the following**?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading a vocabulary book came across with:

1. > The excellent soup was harbinger of the delicious meal to follow.

I am confused of the "**to follow**". I know we can say "a delicious meal **to eat**" which conveys that it is a delicious meal for eating purposes!. However, I think the author tries to convey a sequence of actions happening subsequently one after another, e.i., first soup is eaten and then an awesome meal is waiting for us!. If not, why the author didn't say:

2. > The excellent soup was harbinger of the following delicious meal.

---

In brief,

Q1: Is there any difference between 1 and 2?

Q2: Given to the context, does "**delicious meal to follow**" mean:

There must be a good meal after this awesome soup. I'd better to stay and wait for the meal.(You talk to yourself and draw a conclusion based on the soup quality, speaking with doubt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

> ...something *to follow*.

means

> ...something **that is/was** *to follow*.

which essentially points out that 'something' has not yet occurred/appeared at the time of speaking, but was expected (modal use of the verb "be", omitted there).

As far as the soup in the sentence, it was likely *good*, as much as to *introduce* the rest of the meal, to be its *announcer*.

When '**to follow**' is replaced with the plain '**following**' it does not describe the feeling of being *unrealized yet anticipated* the '**to follow**' indicates.

Comment: so, I was right about the author's intent, draw conclusion based on current observations .. .?

Comment: @Cardinal: don't rush into accepting any answer.  Give other folks a chance to put their best foot forward.  Wait at least a day, then accept.  I don't mind you accepted my answer, but what if it's not right?  Others need to have an opportunity to review it, to upvote, maybe, or downvote.

Comment: Bazaref : Thanks for your advice but I saw your advice completely randomly. I am very busy these days and I hardly can wait to investigate answers. I do agree with you. However, I've seen your answers before. I know you somehow.